# How to use tracing properly in IDA

Tags: debugging, assembly, trace, ida

I'd like to put a breakpoint to some instruction after it's reached, then collect all the tracing info about functions until the same instruction is reached again and stoppet at the same breakpoint.

- I tried to set some breakpoint settings aside from "break" ("trace", "enable tracing" for functions), in this case the tracing window remains empty.
- I left the "break" option only and selected `Debugger - Tracing - Functions trancing`, in this case the tracing info started to appear in the corresponding window, but "Continue process" (F9) started working like the "Step over" (F8), so I was needed to press (hold) the F9 button all the time.

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?